# Laravel 4 RESTful API resource controllers

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel, laravel-4, restful-url

Im developing a Laravel 4 RESTful JSON application.

The application is based around resource controllers bound with repositories / interfaces using Laravel 4's amazing IoC abilities.

Currently i have the following resources:

- Users
- Events
- Activities

Although i have come to a point in the application development where i need to represent a "dashboard" that will be displaying a mixture of these resources in an "activity feed".

As this does not relate to a discreet resource should i be creating a standard DashboardController class? and how would i fit this into my current Model / Controller / Interface / Repository ... setup?

*( as a side note the reason im developing it as a RESTful JSON API is that the application will have three interfaces web, iOS app, Android app.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of question always come when we try to build a RESTful application. You have two options :

1. You try to abstract the situation to link a page to an existing resource (for example a user#show page displaying the activity of this user and not the user itself).
2. You create a dedicated controller, wich could be RESTful, not linked to a specific resource.

I try to use the first solution when I can but it's generally impossible to build an entire app with this pattern for two reasons : some pages can't be link to a resource, even with a lot of abstraction skills, and generally we have more pages or services than REST verbs * resources.

In your case, I would have created a DashboardController. It can be RESTfull if you just create an index method, for example, and it's not really in conflict with your global design.

Comment: These were also my thoughts. As hard as one tries to stick to a particular design pattern, the reality of application development will usually require departures from this.

Thanks for the confirmation ;-)